# Structure and performance (collections, documents, subdocuments)

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on my private project, which will work with MongoDB. I want to get the best performance so I would like to ask you which option will be most the efficient.

Project will collect a lot of data. It will be like:
Company A has X documents, Company B has Y documents, and these companies will work with this data in real time.. so performance in this case it's a big thing.

I wouldn't like to collect all the data (of these companies) in one collection. In the documentation I noticed that there no major problems with the maximum number of collections so my first idea was to save this data like that:

```
 COLLECTION:   ID(company_a)_News 
        Documents will be news from company A

 COLLECTION:   ID(company_b)_News 
        Documents will be news from company B

 ... and so forth ...
```

In this case company X will only work with their subdocuments.

My second idea, which seems unrealistic (too many subdocuments?):

```
Collection: COMPANY
   Document: {Company_ID}
     Subdocument: {News}
        Subsubdocument: {News_id} :     {data.....}
```

In this case company X will get data from "company_id" documents, which will be collected in "company" collection.

Thank you for advice!

Comment: Third idea: store all documents in the same collection, don't embed too much. Speaking from experience :)

Comment: But it could be a problem when i will be work with data from only one company. For example: company X has 1 000 000 documents and company Y has 100 documents and I would like to search specifing documents from company Y documents... so it could be slowly...

Comment: Index documents by `company_id`, of course.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with Sergio. Using different collections that store the same data is bull, with very few exceptions (fast deletes, essentially). Over-Embedding is a typical beginner's mistake, watch out.

Comment: So what do you think about my ideas (create dedicated collections for companies)? Maybe other ideas?

Comment: a) too broad question. Please try your ideas first and come back when you experience actual problems. b) There is a nifty little feature called [indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/). Creating one over the field denoting the company and otherwise following the advice of @SergioTulentsev is actually worth a try. c) You might want to [(re-)take the tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: And I would listen closely to @mnemosyn . Overembedding leads to problems with the maximum document size of 16MB (especially in your example with millions of embedded documents) and frequent document migrations (in general).